# hausdorff, intersection of all closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Can you please help me with this question?

> Let's $X$ be a topological space.
>   Show that these two following conditions are equivalent :
>
> 1. $X$ is hausdorff
> 2. for all $x\in X$ intersection of all closed sets containing the neighborhoods of $x$ it's $\{x\}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show one implication?

Comment: What does "containing the neighborhoods of $x$" mean?

Comment: @William: I’m reasonably certain that Lilly means that the intersection of all closed nbhds of $x$ is $\{x\}$, ‘closed sets containing the neighborhoods of $x$’ being ‘closed sets having $x$ in their interiors’.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the definition of Hausdorff:

> $X$ is a Hausdorff space if for every two distinct $x,y\in X$ there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.

Suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff and $x\in X$. Suppose $y\neq x$. We have $U,V$ as in the definition. So $x\in U$ and $y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Suppose that $F$ is a closed set containing an open neighborhood of $x$, intersecting this open set with $U$ yields an open neighborhood of $x$ which is a subset of $F$ so without loss of generality $U\subseteq F$. $F'=F\cap(X\setminus V)$ is closed and does not contain $y$. Furthermore $U$ itself is a subset of this closed set and $y\notin F'$. Therefore when intersecting *all* closed subsets which contain an open environment of $x$ we remove every other $y$, so the result is $\{x\}$.

---

On the other hand, suppose that for every $x\in X$ this intersection is $\{x\}$, by a similar process as above deduce that $X$ is Hausdorff as in the definition above.

Answer (score 9):

HINTS:

1. If $x$ and $y$ are distinct points in a Hausdorff space, they have disjoint open nbhds $V_x$ and $V_y$, and $X\setminus V_y$ is a closed set containing $V_x$.
2. If $F$ is a closed set containing an open nbhd $V$ of $x$, then $V$ and $X\setminus F$ are disjoint open sets.

Comment: How do you know that the closed set $F$ contains a nbhd $V$ of $x$?